# Why does CefSharp.WebBrowserExtensions.SetZoomLevel affect all instances?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have an application that can have multiple windows and in each window there is a custom `UserControl` that hosts a `CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser` control.

I can change the zoom level of the browser using `CefSharp. WebBrowserExtensions. SetZoomLevel` with no problems.

The only issue I have is that when doing so the zoom level of *all browser instances* (in all of the separate windows) changes.

Why is that so and how can it be prevented? I find it surprising that the call to `SetZoomLevel` is passed a specific control instance, but all other instances are also affected.

P.S.: I'm using CEF 3.2454.1344.g2782fb8 (Chromium  45.0.2454.101).

Comment: Apparently this is by-chrome-design, see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390775). The zoom levels are linked by domain, i.e. all control instances browsing pages of the same domain share a common zoom level. Since I am using Cef as a UI, which is being served by my own server, all pages are at `http://localhost`. Does anyone have any ideas how to circumvent this "feature"?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the zoom level is linked per ***sub**-domain*. If I used "http://window1.localhost" and "http://window2.localhost" I can adjust the zoom levels independently.

Comment: Interesting workaround! The other option is to isolate them using a `RequestContext`, I cannot remember if that's available in version `45`, you might have needed to upgrade to `47`. Basically by default they share a `Global RequestContext`, there are many features that can be specified on the `RequestContext` level so it's a handy one to look into.